# jQuery and CSS positioning conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm writing a small viewer for a few images. I'm having trouble and I'm not sure what the cause is, but my guess is it's the mixture of CSS and jQuery that goes on.

The problems are:

- The images twitch a little when others are animating.
- After the first time animating the images move lower than their original positions

The code might be a little messy because I had to change a bunch of things to get the fiddle working.

My HTML markup:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="photos">
            <figure class="photo">
                <img class="photo-image" src="http://bite-dose.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/cute-baby-animals.jpg"/>
            </figure>
            <figure class="photo">
                <img class="photo-image" src="http://cdn.arkarthick.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/blissfully-cute-baby-animals-baby-squirrel-6.jpg"/>
            </figure>
            <figure class="photo">
                <img class="photo-image" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_4CngMC7D0HE/TDDHJ73_qJI/AAAAAAAAALY/-8Rvz41kRnc/s1600/baby_monkey_blanket.jpg"/>
            </figure>
            <figure class="photo">
                <img class="photo-image" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_sIsR_xZ02MY/S_es3PlQIrI/AAAAAAAABGQ/ud3iEaMiu4w/s1600/cute_baby_animals_T3509_seal.jpg"/>
            </figure>
            <figure class="photo">
                <img class="photo-image" src="http://xaxor.com/images/baby-animals-part3-/baby-animals-part3-12.jpg"/>
            </figure>
            <figure class="photo">
                <img class="photo-image" src="http://nrbrose.edublogs.org/files/2011/05/blissfully-cute-baby-animals-baby-elephant-11-178o61g.jpg"/>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <hr/><br/><br/>
    </body>
</html>
​
```

My CSS:

```
#photos  {
    display : block;
    position: relative;
}

.photo {
    border    : 1px solid #808080;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
    position  : absolute;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width : 250px;
}

.photo {
    display: block;
}

.photo:hover {
            transform: rotate( 0deg ) !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ) !important;
       -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ) !important;
        -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ) !important;
         -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ) !important;
    z-index: 1;
}

.photo-image {
    display   : block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width : 100%;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px dashed red;
}
​
```

My JavaScript:

```
SemiEllipse = function ( a, b, cx, cy ) {
    this.radiusA = a;
    this.radiusB = b;
    this.radiusASquared = a * a;
    this.radiusBSquared = b * b;
    this.centerX = cx || 0;
    this.centerY = cy || 0;
}

SemiEllipse.prototype = {
    getPoint: function ( x ) {
        x -= this.radiusA;
        var y = this.radiusB * Math.sqrt( 1 - ( ( x * x ) / this.radiusASquared ) );

        return { x: x + this.centerX, y: y + this.centerY };
    },

    getAngle: function ( x ) {
        var angle = Math.PI/2 - Math.atan2( this.radiusB, x );
        return angle;
    }
}

$( '#photos' ).each(function () {
    var $photogroup = $( this );
    var $photos     = $photogroup.find( '.photo' );
    var count       = $photos.length;
    var limitHeight = $photos.css( 'max-height' );
    var maxHeight   = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        var $photo = $photos.eq( i );
        var h = $photo.height();

        if ( h > maxHeight ) {
            maxHeight = h;
        }
        if ( maxHeight > limitHeight ) {
            maxHeight = limitHeight;
            break;
        }
    }

    $photogroup.height( 400 );

    var bounds = {
        w   : $photogroup.width(),
        h   : $photogroup.height(),
        padW: $photogroup.innerWidth() - $photogroup.width(), 
        padH: $photogroup.innerHeight() - $photogroup.height(), 
    }
    var halfW = bounds.w / 2;
    var scale = halfW / ( count - 1 );
    var sc = new SemiEllipse( halfW / 2, 100 );

    // PHOTO POSITIONING
    for ( var i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        var $photo = $photos.eq( i );
        var p     = sc.getPoint( i * scale );
        var theta = sc.getAngle( p.x ) / 10;

        $photo.css({
            'left'  : p.x + sc.radiusA,
            'bottom': p.y,
            'transform': 'rotate( ' + theta + 'rad )',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate( ' + theta + 'rad )',
            '-mox-transform': 'rotate( ' + theta + 'rad )',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate( ' + theta + 'rad )',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate( ' + theta + 'rad )',
        });
    }

    // HOVER FUNCTIONS
    $photos.each(function () {
        $this = $( this );
        var y = parseFloat( $this.css('bottom') );

        $this.data('mouseOverBottom', y + 10)
        .data('mouseOutBottom',  y - 10)
        .css({
            'transition': 'all .25s ease-in-out',
            '-webkit-transition': 'all .25s ease-in-out', 
            '-moz-transition': 'all .25s ease-in-out', 
            '-o-transition': 'all .25s ease-in-out'
        });
    }).hover(function () {
        $this = $( this );
        $this.css( 'bottom', $this.data( 'mouseOverBottom' ) );
    }, function () {
        $this = $( this );
        $this.css( 'bottom', $this.data( 'mouseOutBottom' ) );
    });
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/rNnx4/16/

I'm not sure about the images moving lower, but I've dealt with the twitching before. I already know that `transform: translateZ(0)` will do the trick, but this seems to kill my rotations. The only way I can think of getting it working is by adding a `<div>` around every image with a class doing that, but I'm stubborn and don't want to add `<div>`s to all of my things. But I guess I'll suck it up if it's the only way.

Comment: Please don't post fiddles as questions. Your question must contain all the code necessary to provide an answer, without anybody ever accessing the fiddle. Before you post a question here, you should reduce your code to the smallest size which still reproduces your problems. In the process, you'll probably figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/rNnx4/17/ Aparently in your original, animating the rotation imposed problems to all images that **are after the rotated image in source** (i.e. try on monkey, all after it flicker). There is also a problem if there is no room for every image, noticeable in the last image if you resize the window (it shrinks till fade away, then a glitch on right). Also if you are happy with this effect there is a cleanup to do regarding angle code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You identified two issues:

> - The images twitch a little when others are animating.

This can be fixed by adding a `translate3d(0,0,0)` to each transform (both in the CSS and in the JS). This 'hack' forces the browser to render each div on it's own layer and adds hardware acceleration if applicable. It can be a performance/memory hit on mobile devices.

I'm not sure what exactly the root cause was; as Niloct pointed out, only images that are "on top" are affected, so nothing jiggles when you hover over the elephant. If you assign individual z-indexes in reverse order (so the hamster is on top), nothing jiggles when hovering over the hamster.

My guess is that the browser is rendering anything that needs to be recalculated (the drop shadows on the photos that would appear over the hovered photo while the `z-index` transitions from 0->1) on one layer, and the jiggling is anti-aliasing as each frame in the transition is rendered.

> - After the first time animating the images move lower than their original positions

Your code has each photo start at `bottom: 0`. On `mouseOver`, `bottom: 10`. On `mouseOut`, `bottom: -10`, and it will remain at -10 for the rest of the life of the tab. Could be fixed by setting `mouseOver = 20` and `mouseOut = 0`.

Both changes implemented on your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rNnx4/19/